# Converting HttpRequest.QueryString to object[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert a [HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) to `object[]` with this extension method:

```
public static object[] ToObjectArray(this NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    var ret = new object[nvc.Count];

    var count = 0;
    foreach (string s in nvc)
    {
        var strings = nvc.GetValues(s);
        if (strings != null)
        {
            foreach (string v in strings)
            {
                ret[count] = new { s = v };
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    return ret;
}

var args = request.QueryString.ToObjectArray();
```

I think that I'm pretty close, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
Object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' 
cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert v to a new object, a string is already an object, so you can just do:

```
ret[count] = v;
```

Here's a slightly shorter way, using a list to avoid having to keep up with the array index.

```
public static object[] ToObjectArray(this NameValueCollection nvc) {
    List<object> results = new List<object>();
    foreach (string key in nvc.Keys) {
        results.Add(nvc.GetValues(key));
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with `return (from string key in nvc.Keys select nvc.GetValues(key)).Cast<object>().ToArray();`